# How does Diver movement work in forbidden island?

Tags: forbidden-island

I played my first few games of Forbidden Island last night, and one of the roles we played was the Diver. We weren't 100% sure of the meaning of his special ability, so I wanted to ask if anyone had any clarification to make sure we play correctly in future.

The Diver's ability (from memory, edit if incorrect) says:

> The Diver may move through any number of flooded or sunken tiles for 1 action

does this mean that the Diver can move to any land tile connected by flooded/sunken tiles? Or does it mean that moving through any number of such tiles is 1 action, and emerging onto land again is a second action?

to illustrate, here is an example:
let **X** be a sunken tile, **T** be a regular tile, and **FT** be a flooded tile.

**T1 - FT1 - X - FT2 - T2**.

Does moving the diver from T1 to T2 constitute 1 action, or 2 (one to move to FT2, and one to move the last square)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got it right the first time. In your example, it takes the diver 1 move action to go from T1 to T2. The Diver is incredibly useful for quickly getting around the island while it's flooded. It's not as overpowered as it would initially seem... until tiles start sinking, the Diver hasn't any other special abilities. In later stages of the game, you can ensure he'll probably survive.

Comment: Isn't the diver impossible to lose due to his ability to use swim when moving away from a sunken tile?

Comment: No. If the Diver is caught in a sunken tile and there's no adjacent tile to get to, you lose, just like all the other roles.

Comment: Neither the pilot nor the diver may die unless they are on the last tile. End of page 7 of the rules. "Exceptions: The Diver may swim to the nearest tile. The Explorer may swim diagonally. 
The Pilot may fly to any tile."

Comment: Oh good, I stand corrected.

Comment: @Guvante Regarding the diver, what if there are no remaining tiles that are available only by moving in a straight line up/down/left/right? How can the diver swim to them?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found the answer from the creator of the game, himself. The answer is that the Diver can 'turn' on flooded and/or missing tiles: http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/524604/diver-questions